# Passing One Property to an Otherwise Empty, New Object in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular

I am trying to create a new record via a post request to our API by basically passing an empty document. Our API (mongoDB/Node) then responds by auto-incrementing/creating a new empty object with just an ID, which is passed back to me. I use this id to handle navigation. A user can then add info to this empty document. It is working as is. However, the one thing we want to pass is "deleted: true" as an initial state for this new empty document, so it doesn't show up in search records until data has been entered. This is what I'm trying:

```
    createRecord() {
        const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        const body = JSON.stringify({deleted: true});
        return this._http.post
        ('https://api.somesite.com/v0/records?apikey=someapikey',
        body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
   }
```

The key line is this one:

```
const body = JSON.stringify({deleted: true});
```

Is this how I would pass this? Should this work as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a JSON object not a string

`const body = {deleted: true};`

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't need to stringify in this instance, just pass an object. Thanks @artemisian